# In Access 2002 VBA, what datatype can be used to limit the precision of a double result?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm performing a calulation that results in a floating point number. When I try and write it to a Access field, I get this error:

`Run-time error '3759': Scaling of decimal value resulted in data truncation`

I've intentionally limited the access field to a fixed precision. I was hoping that the value would be automatically truncated, but instead it's throwing this error - how can I explicitly change the precision of the value in VBA to avoid this error?

Code:

```
value = X / Y
With myTAble
    .AddNew
    !calc = value
    .Update
End With
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using VBA's Round function, as in:

```
!calc = Round(value, 2)
```

Replace the 2 with however many decimal places you want.

Depending on the scale and precision of your numbers, you might still encounter the 3759 error if Round returns a value that cannot be expressed exactly as a Double floating point number (and so ends up having more decimal places than you asked for).  A more robust approach might be to use something like:

```
!calc = CDec(FormatNumber(value, 2))
```

Replace the 2 with however many decimal places you want.

FormatNumber will round the number and convert it to a string (with only the number of decimal places that you specify), and CDec will convert the string into a Decimal.

Comment: I like this approach better then mine. Just note that in these cases you'll get a rounded number (not a truncated one).

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
value = X / Y
With myTAble
    .AddNew
    !calc = Fix(value*10^decimalPlaces)/10^decimalPlaces
    .Update
End With
```

Where `decimalPlaces` is the number of decimal places that you wish to work with.

`Fix` truncates the number. If you wish some kind of rounding, try `Clng`.

Comment: `Val` takes a string and converts it to a number, or returns zero if it can't.

Comment: @Eduardo: You're right. I tested `? Val(9.87)` at the immediate window and it returned just `9`. But it seems to be a kind of misbehaviour. I'll correct my answer. Thanks.

Comment: `Val` takes a string and outputs a number. If you wanted to get `9.87`, you should have used `? Val("9.87")`.